# Positioning absolutely vs using table?

Tags: css

Ok following scenario:

we support 
1.desktop, 2.tablet and 3.smartphone

so the page has to look good on all 3 of them.
What I did so far is use a table to create the look of the contact page. E.g. some text next to the picture of the page owner.

Then a seperate table with all infos again for the tablet version, when it is in portrait mode, since there is less space in width, i rearrange things. So a new table, with all infos again (phone number name etc). Now same story *again* for the smartphone view.

Although using tables for this page feels right, since all is aligned next to each other, duplicating all information feels so wrong.

Is there something that really speaks against using absolutely positioned elements instead? e.g. wrap name phone number in a div, position it absolutely next to the picture which is positioned absolutely too. THen change the position for smartphone / tablet.

Does something actually speak against the absolute positioned approach?

is there something i might be missing entirely?

Comment: It's hard to know what you're talking about with no examples. But for sure absolute positioning will not be the answer.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question but sounds like what grid systems were designed to do. No need to reinvent the wheel here: [base](https://matthewhartman.github.io/base/), [ink](http://ink.sapo.pt/), [skeleton](http://getskeleton.com/) etc.

Comment: search for `responsive webdesign`: you can alter the tables and cells behavior with breakpoints and media queries.

Comment: @cabellicar123 no [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)?

Comment: @karaokyo Figured that was more than the OP needed but yes also [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/build.html)

Comment: I think grid systems like that are a thing of the past and get more into my way than they are actually helpful.

Comment: @Toskan tables are moreso a thing of the past...

Comment: @karaokyo so what are you using to display tabular data? I mean nobody likes tables, but hey, they are meant to be used for some stuff.

Comment: Avoid Plugins (unless you *know* they're doing what you want). Maybe absolutely positioning elements here isn't ***entirely*** what you're looking for, but maybe you could use display properties instead? (Primarily inline-blocks?). You might then want to use media queries for your phone stuff, and tablets should be quite close to your desktop css? This would leave minimal markup for your needs.

Comment: @jbutler483 display properties is what I finally ended up using, but I had to duplicate the texts 3 times. I still don't understand what speak against absolute positioning. Say I set a div as background with position relative, fixed width and height depending on the viewport width, then set the elements inside it.